# perform oauth with ios6 twitter framework

Tags: twitter, ios6

Is it possible to do a oauth login to twitter through ios6 twitter framework instead of having to use unofficial third party libraries such as twitter+oauth. Using the ios6 official twitter framework is better as it is well documented. Any help is appreciated.